# If I get transaction hash by PersonalSendTransaction, It means the transactions always be mined？

Tags: transactions

I want to know if I get the transaction hash by PersonalSendTransaction, Whether It means the transaction will be mined in eth and will not be lost?

If not, whether should I record the hash and check the receipt periodly, and if I don't got the right receipt (with block hash) in one hour, recall PersonalSendTransaction?

Ignore the price problem. I build a private eth network for a project.

Answer (score 1):

Simply receiving a transaction hash is not a guarantee of it being mined. There are a number of reasons that could lead to a transaction being dropped, such as your node having no peers, a max gas that exceeds the block gas limit, or nonce duplication, among others.

You should certainly be recording the transaction hash, and check for a tx receipt before concluding that it is final. You may also want to wait for a number of blocks to be mined on top of the block containing your tx, depending on your network organization.